# Why does my .Net 4.6.2 console app incorrectly reference .net core Class Library Project?

Tags: .net-core

I have a .Net Core Class Library which can be nicely referenced successfully from a .Net Core Console App.

I am trying to reference the class library from a .Net 4.6.2 console app now, and it seems to reference ok, but when I try to instantiate an object from the .Net Core Lib, it can't find it. Oddly enough if I try to add a reference to the DLL directly using the /bin/Debug folder of the .Net Core Class Lib it works...

It also works if I package it up as a nuget package and add it that way. My .Net Core Class Library's project.json is below. You can see the whole solution in ObjectHydrator at https://github.com/PrintsCharming/ObjectHydrator/tree/v2-alpha-1

```
    {
  "version": "2.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {

  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "dependencies": {
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "netcoreapp": {
      "dependencies": { "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.1.0" },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it is possible to add dependency to .Net Core Class Library only via Nuget. This is cause the new project templates/.xproj works a bit differently.

Assembly references should be supported directly again with the move to use csproj projects for .NET Core ([referencing third party dll's](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/731) issue)

Comment: Well then I guess I was doing it "right". Do you know when this will get addressed? Is it in VS "15"?